# Prevent NSTableRowView from changing highlight when not in focus?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I've got an NSSplitView with a table view in the left pane. I've noticed that when I have an item selected in the left pane and I change focus to the right pane, the left pane loses focus and the highlighted row's highlight color turns to gray and the text turns black.

I have overridden the highlight color by overriding `drawSelectionInRect` in NSTableRowView. By doing this, the highlight color remains the same custom color, but the text turns dark which looks wrong.

Can I either let the highlight color change when the table view is out of focus, or prevent the text from turning dark when it's out of focus?

Comment: Is the text field subview of `NSTableRowView` or `NSTableCellView`?

Comment: Assuming you have a view-based table view, what is the kind of views you have for drawing the content?

Comment: It's a subview of an `NSTableCellView`. The view is just something I put together in IB.

Comment: @Aaron don't use `textField`-outlet of `NSTableCellView`. Use another one instead.

Comment: @Astoria I gave that a try but the text color changed anyway. It's like the highlight style is getting changed when that moves out of focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that OS X calls setBackgroundStyle on the row view and its subviews when you click on the other view in the split view. Interestingly it seems to only happen to NSOutlineView.

Since I have code in place already to handle changing my images to different images when rows are selected (for improved contrast), and I am explicitly setting the background style when I need to using `outlineViewSelectionDidChange` and `outlineViewSelectionIsChanging` I overrode `setBackgroundStyle` to be a no-op and I made my own custom setter which changed the `_backgroundStyle` ivar.

It looks like this:

```
@implementation TextFieldWithHighlighting
@synthesize backgroundStyle = _backgroundStyle;
- (NSBackgroundStyle) backgroundStyle {
    return _backgroundStyle;
}
@synthesize secretBackgroundStyle = _secretBackgroundStyle;
- (NSBackgroundStyle) secretBackgroundStyle {
    return _backgroundStyle;
}

- (void)setBackgroundStyle:(NSBackgroundStyle)backgroundStyle {

}

- (void) setSecretBackgroundStyle:(NSBackgroundStyle)secretBackgroundStyle {
    _backgroundStyle = secretBackgroundStyle;
    self.needsDisplay = YES;
}


- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    if(_backgroundStyle == NSBackgroundStyleDark) {
        if(self.originalTextColor == nil) {
            self.originalTextColor = self.textColor;
        }
        self.textColor = [NSColor whiteColor];
    } else {
        if(self.originalTextColor) {
            self.textColor = self.originalTextColor;
        } else {
            self.textColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0x40/255.0 green:0x40/255.0 blue:0x41/255.0 alpha:0xFF/255.0];
        }
    }
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

}

@end
```

It only works for me because I am explicitly handling rows changing their selection and AFAIK I am not relying anywhere on the OS changing it for me. If I could do it again I'd just push for using the system highlight color in which case I get this functionality for free.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a small contribution to your answer. This works as well with the weird contrast generated with the `drawSelectionInRect` implementation. Here's a Swift solution that also works implemented in an `NSTableCellView`:

```
    override var backgroundStyle: NSBackgroundStyle {
             get {
                 return self.backgroundStyle
            }

             set {

            }         
        }
```